# Как кастомизировать {{ ansible_managed }}?

Tags: ansible

Нужно изменить информацию что выводит `{{ ansible_managed }}`

Comment: Скажите, а что именно вы хотите там выводить? Какой результат нужен?

Answer (score 2):

По Ansible есть доступная [документация](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#ansible-managed)...

```
ansible_managed = Ansible managed
```

В `ansible.cfg`.

Comment: О, я смотрю с большого so знакомые никнеймы подтягиваются! Здравствуйте, Константин, рад буду видеть в этом теге.